# Error while applying patch for httpd-2.4.7

Tags: linux, git, apache, ssl, rpmbuild

I downloaded a source rpm for httpd-2.4.7 from koji.fedoraproject.org, When i try to build the  package i get a error stating that " Only garbage value was found in the patch input".

The patch name is httpd-2.4.7-sslsninotreq.patch.

The whole content of the patch is as follows.

```
diff --git a/modules/ssl/ssl_engine_config.c b/modules/ssl/ssl_engine_config.c
index 15993f1..53ed6f1 100644
```

But the previous version of the same patch (i.e) httpd-2.4.3-sslsninotreq.patch had a lot more lines than the above.

Is this because of a fault commit from git? or is there anything that i should install on my system like git before building the package ?

Do anyone else have the same problem ? is there any other source of this patch available ?

Comment: What you posted is an empty patch.

Comment: I have gone through the original source of the patch, it has only those two lines.
I downloaded the source rpm from http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/httpd/2.4.7/1.fc20/src/httpd-2.4.7-1.fc20.src.rpm
is this because of a fault commit from git ?
where should i report this issue ? I appreciate your time.

Comment: You should ask the maintainer of Fedora's httpd package about this.

Comment: Ok thanks, i have raised this issue to the package builder.